# Python reference integer variables

Tags: python, reference

This is a sample in python about list type's reference:

```
li = [1,2,3]
ref_li = li

ref_li[0]=2
print(li) #[2,2,3]
```

We can simply use the `=` operator to make a reference for list. And this way, if we change any index into different value with `ref_li`, it will also change for `li`.

But when I use `=` operator to reference a variable that stores integer:

```
var = 3
ref_var = var

ref_var = 0
print(var) #3
```

The original variable doesn't seem to change.

[Q1]:
I'm wonder if it's possible to reference a variable that stores an integer like this, but it alters the original variable `var` if you change the reference variable `ref_var`?

What I also know is, if you change the whole list in the first example:

```
li = [1,2,3]
ref_li = li

ref_li=[2,2,3]
print(li) #[1,2,3]
```

The result, just like the second example, doesn't seem to affect the original variable `li`.

[Q2] Is it possible to reference a list variable like this, and the original variable `li` alters if you change the **whole** list to the reference variable `ref_li`?

Comment: `ref_li[0] = 2` isn't an assignment to `ref_li`; it's syntax for a method call `ref_li.__setitem__(0, 2)` that *mutates* the original list. `ref_var = 0` *is* an assignment to a name that has nothing to do with the original value assigned to `rev_var`. `var` itself is *also* a reference to an `int` object; `rev_var` is simply *another* reference to the same object.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: In fact, you do not assign to `li` a new value, you _mutate_ the referred list through another reference. There's no pass-by-reference semantics in the sense of C++. Since `int` is immutable there's no way to mutate it like that.

Comment: @bereal So what does **reference** actually do in python? Why does the first example work? @chepner said, it's same as ```ref_li.__setitem__(0,2)```, but why does it alter the original list? If a referenced variable altered by built-in method always alter the original variable, then `a=3; b=a; b+=1` should also alter `a`, since `b+=1` means `b.__add__(1)`.

Comment: @Acc-lab did you read the link above?

Comment: @bereal I think I understand the most, but I still don't know what's the difference between the two bulit-in methods I said above. What's the **key point** of difference between altering or not altering the original variable?

Comment: `rel_fi.__setitem__` modifies the list referred by `rel_fi`. On the other hand, `b.__add__` create a _new_ integer without affecting the original one, and binds the new value to `b`.

Comment: @bereal I think I understand. `b.__iadd__(a)` is same to `b=b.__add__(a)`, which is not the original variable's reference. Is that correct?

Comment: @Acc-lab well, to make it a bit more confusing, `b += a` is `b = b.__iadd(a)__` if such method exists, and `b = b.__add__(a)` otherwise. And in the case of `list`, `__iadd__` _modifies the same list_ without creating a copy, so the effect of `rel_fi += [1]` will be visible to `li`. So the behaviour of `b += a` depends on whether this type is mutable.

Comment: @bereal I get it. Thank you.